# Spring AOP with mule

Tags: logging, mule, interceptor, spring-aop, jamon

I am using Spring AOP for perf stats with JAMon apis.

```
    public class ServicePerformanceInterceptor extends JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor {
        @Override
        protected Object invokeUnderTrace(MethodInvocation invocation, Log logger) throws Throwable {
.
.
.

    }
```

And bean configuration

```
<bean id="timingAdvice" class="com.example.logging.interceptor.ServicePerformanceInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.example.resource.Resource.*(..))" advice-ref="timingAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
```

But in the flow interceptor is not getting invoked. Can you please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What's your full configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that, I need to set log4j property to trace level. Else it will fail to invoke.